# Erro Class 'app\Curso' not found

Tags: php, laravel

Estou com esse erro ao fazer a listagem de todos os cursos em um CRUD no Laravel

"Class 'app\Curso' not found"

Sendo que existe essa classe, irei mostrar em códigos e imagens...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código do controller:

```
<?php

namespace app\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use app\Curso;

class CursosController 

    extends Controller
    {
        public function index(){
            $registros = Curso::all();
            return view('admin.cursos.index', compact('registros'));
        }
    }
```

Código da Classe

```
<?php

namespace app;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class Curso extends Model
{
    //
}
```

Grato se puderem me ajudar, pois é um trabalho da faculdade!

Comment: Só da erro com o model de cursos? Abre o model de usuário e compara com o de cursos.

Comment: use App\Curso    ... App inicia com letra maiúscula. E no model o namespace é App .. com letra maíuscula tmb..  Olha no teu composer.json ... psr-4 .. "App\\": "app/" ..

Comment: @DarleiFernandoZillmer Sobre a edição, Laravel é um nome próprio que refere-se ao framework PHP. Ele não deve estar com a formatação de código.

Answer (score 2):

Você precisa alterar duas coisas.

No Model use:

```
namespace App;
```

E no Controller:

```
use App\Curso;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ao invés de

```
use app\Curso;
```

tente

```
use App\Curso;
```